# スキーマ名をクエリに書かずにスキーマを指定したクエリを実行したい

Tags: sql, postgresql

質問：
　スキーマ名をクエリに書かずに以下を実現する方法はありますか？

環境：
 postgreSQL 9.x
 windows
 できればpgAdmin4で実行したい
 （cmdから実行するには不慣れなため）

実現したいこと：
　①と同じ結果を②で得る

①
SELECT *
FROM schemaA.tableA

②
SELECT *
FROM tableA

Comment: schemaAをデフォルトスキーマとしないユーザ(ロール)からSELECTしたいということでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

対象のスキーマにサーチパスを設定することで実現できませんか？

https://kanamelogic.com/20180427/search_path/